# How to solve "RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported" in multi-class classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, data-science

Our goal is to build a multi-class image classifier using Pytorch and based on the EMNIST dataset (black and white pictures of letters).

The shape of our training data X_train is (124800, 28, 28).

The shape of the original target variables y_train is (124800, 1), however, we created a one-hot encoding so that now the shape is (124800, 26).

The model that we are building should have 26 output variables, each representing the probability of one letter.

We read in our data as follows:

```
import scipy .io
emnist = scipy.io.loadmat(DATA_DIR + '/emnist-letters.mat')
data = emnist ['dataset']
X_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['images'][0, 0]
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,28,28), order='F')

y_train = data ['train'][0, 0]['labels'][0, 0]
```

Then, we created a one-hot-encoding as follows:

```
y_train_one_hot = np.zeros([len(y_train), 27])

for i in range (0, len(y_train)):
    y_train_one_hot[i, y_train[i][0]] = 1
    
y_train_one_hot = np.delete(y_train_one_hot, 0, 1)
```

We create the dataset with:

```
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_train), torch.from_numpy(y_train_one_hot))

batch_size = 128
n_iters = 3000
num_epochs = n_iters / (len(train_dataset) / batch_size)
num_epochs = int(num_epochs)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, 
                                           batch_size=batch_size, 
                                           shuffle=True)
```

And then we build our model as follows:

```
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Convolution 1
        self.cnn1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        
        # Max pool 1
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
     
        # Convolution 2
        self.cnn2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        
        # Max pool 2
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        # Fully connected 1 (readout)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 4 * 4, 26) 

    def forward(self, x):
        # Convolution 1
        out = self.cnn1(x.float())
        out = self.relu1(out)
        
        # Max pool 1
        out = self.maxpool1(out)
        
        # Convolution 2 
        out = self.cnn2(out)
        out = self.relu2(out)
        
        # Max pool 2 
        out = self.maxpool2(out)
        
        # Resize
        # Original size: (100, 32, 7, 7)
        # out.size(0): 100
        # New out size: (100, 32*7*7)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)

        # Linear function (readout)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        
        return out

model = CNNModel()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

learning_rate = 0.01

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)
```

And then we train the model as follows:

```
iter = 0
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        # Add a single channel dimension
        # From: [batch_size, height, width]
        # To: [batch_size, 1, height, width]
        images = images.unsqueeze(1)

        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)
        
        # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)

        # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
        loss.backward()
        
        # Updating parameters
        optimizer.step()
        
        iter += 1
        
        if iter % 500 == 0:
            # Calculate Accuracy         
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through test dataset
            for images, labels in test_loader:
               
                images = images.unsqueeze(1)
                
                # Forward pass only to get logits/output
                outputs = model(images)
                
                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                
                # Total number of labels
                total += labels.size(0)
                
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
            
            accuracy = 100 * correct / total
            
            # Print Loss
            print('Iteration: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}'.format(iter, loss.data[0], accuracy))
```

However, when we run this, we get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c26c43bbc32e> in <module>()
     21 
     22         # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
---> 23         loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     24 
     25         # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    930     def forward(self, input, target):
    931         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
--> 932                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    933 
    934 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2315     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2316         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2317     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   2318 
   2319 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2113                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2114     if dim == 2:
-> 2115         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2116     elif dim == 4:
   2117         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

We expect that we do something wrong when we initialize/use our loss function. What can we do so that we can start training our model?

Comment: what is the shape of `y_train_one_hot` eventually?

Answer (score -2):

## Institution Name

The Code below will create an html file from a table in your excel file. It will write the entire table and search for the number of lines and columns to write it all that is showing.Please make sure to edit the html section of the table itself. On my example I wanted to transpose lines and columns and print them one by one.Note: A simple macro that will convert your Excel data into a clean HTML table. ... the highlighted cells of an Excel spreadsheet and create a simple HTML table

1. My First Heading
2. none
3. none
4. none

Note: A simple macro that will convert your Excel data into a clean HTML table. ... the highlighted cells of an Excel spreadsheet 
and create a simple HTML table

Comment: I think you might have answered the wrong question there Pathiban. The question is about getting an error and you've replied on how to solve an Excel sheet issue.